# Tap highlight in Safari Mobile and jQuery on() function produce huge highlight

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile-safari

I am using jQuery's `on()` function on iOS' Safari Mobile Browser like this:

```
$("#content").on(".element", click(function(){ do stuff});
```

When clicking on `.element` Safari highlights the whole `#content` area instead of just the area `.element` takes.

When using

```
$(".element").click(function(){do stuff});
```

instead the right area is highlighted. I guess this is the expected behavior but it's not intuitive for the user at all, so I'm looking for a workaround.

I know I can get rid of the highlighting completely by using `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` but I think the highlight is actually pretty useful generally since CSS' hover isn't useful on mobile devices already.

**Is there a way with jQuery's on function and Safari Mobile to get the tap highlight of the `.element`?**

Comment: What do you mean with "to get the tap highlight of the .element"?

Comment: is there a way to use the on() function and at the same time make Safari hightlight only `.element` instead of `#content`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

1. Put `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);` in document ready function enabling the css `:active` pseude class
2. Disabling the tap highlight completely: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`
3. Adding `.element:active{background: #cccccc;}`

This way the clicked (active) element gets a nice gray background when touched.