# Tap Highlight on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I am trying to apply the -webkit-tap-highlight-color CSS to two elements. It works on Android Chrome, but it simply refuses to work on iOS Safari.

```
<div class="right">
    <input id="search-bar" class="" type="text"/> 
    <div id="button-menu" class="right button-clickable"></div>
    <div id="button-search" class="right button-clickable"></div>
</div>

#button-search{
    width: 60px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(../images/svg/magnifying-glass.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: center;
}

#button-menu{
    width: 60px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(../images/svg/menu-dots.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: center;
}

.button-clickable{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #8F7E82;
}
```

Is there something I need to do to enable tap colors on Safari on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

[Tap highlight in Safari Mobile and jQuery on() function produce huge highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674857/tap-highlight-in-safari-mobile-and-jquery-on-function-produce-huge-highlight)

Solved it with this. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.