# Tapping links in iOS Safari shows a thick white border around element - how to get rid of it?

Tags: css, hyperlink, border, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

***Problem***

On my site I see this super strange behaviour on any kind of linked elements (text, images, svg elements, table cells): when long tapping them in Safari on iOS, a thick white border appears before showing the link preview.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image]

***What I have tried so far***

As it's only showing on iOS, I am a bit limited with debugging it, unfortunately.

I have tried to fix it using the following most recommended solutions with link tap in iOS Safari, but neither of them does solve the issue:

```css
html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
a, a:visited, a img {
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
}
input, textarea, button, select, label, a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

***Solution ideas?***

**Does anybody know, or has an idea, how I can get rid of this border** - or at least also make it appear "transparent"?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED: seems like the thick white border is not the border, but related to the *background color* of the element / linked element. And it is controllable through the `:active` state.

**Fixed by adding this to my CSS**:

```css
a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Solution inspired by the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12686281/5750030